# restart apache for specific website

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, bash

I have working on POedit locale translation, after update the .mo files, I have to restart the appache to see the translation changes in my site.

Is there a way to restart apache only for that website to see those changes rather then restarting whole apache?

I am using this command to restart appache

Service httpd restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't restart apache for just one site. Did you try reloading instead of restarting?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am bit confuse about graceful, reload, restart. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Graceful Restart:

Signal: USR1
    apachectl -k graceful

The USR1 or graceful signal causes the parent process to advise the children to exit after their current request (or to exit immediately if they're not serving anything). The parent re-reads its configuration files and re-opens its log files. As each child dies off the parent replaces it with a child from the new generation of the configuration, which begins serving new requests immediately.

Comment: Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/stopping.html .